# Manually activating a theme in wordpress, site is not reachable

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress site is not reachable, how can I manually activate a theme?  (the current theme has a bug in it, I want to revert to the other theme)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go to the file system to change the theme's directory name or even just delete it. In this case, WP should use its default theme.

Comment: This is also the recommended way to disable malfunctioning plug-ins.  Use an FTP client to visit the `/wp-content/themes` (or `/wp-content/plugins/`) folder and either delete or re-name the malfunctioning theme's folder.  WordPress will automatically revert to the default theme when it can't find the set one, allowing you to log in and fix whatever problem came up.

Comment: @EANabb Thanks your detailed supplement. I should consider not only answer the how, but also the why ^^

Comment: fail; WP said 'The theme directory "xxx" does not exist.'

Answer (score 0):

You should go to:

```
public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes
```

And replace its content with the new thime.

(you get there with a FTP client)

Just download a .zip theme (anyone or even better the default one), unzip and upload copying the same structure as the old theme had.

Good luck and be carful, ask if you have doubts before touching anything!